# Iterated integration by parts with multiple variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

Let $\alpha$ be multi-index. Consider the iterated integral
$$\int_{a_n}^{b_n} \cdots \int_{a_1}^{b_1} \left(D^{\alpha}f(x)\right)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}x_n.$$
Does anyone know a slick formula for this, moving all derivatives from $f$ to $g$? Of course, this is just iterated integration by parts, but doing this by hand seems like a huge pain. A simple reference would be sufficient, thanks!